# page loading in document IE 7 mode on some PC's

Tags: internet-explorer

I append a span inside a href link using:               $(this).find("a:first").append(""+ opts.closedSign +"");
works fine BUT on some PC's the span seems to be forced onto a new line. The browser seems to get switched to document IE 7 mode Although the page source is the same and both machines have the same version of IE (8).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check: 1) the site may be forced into compatibility mode by the browsers compatibility settings or 2) there may be an HTTP header in responses telling the browser to run in compatibility mode.

Comment: Thanks for that. I do not really understand the 2nd point as the page and server are the same, and the client machines are on the same network...

Comment: I forced it to behave with a meta tag. Gotte strafe Microsoft.